# Why do I keep getting this error when I press a button?

Tags: javascript, html

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggle' of undefined

Here's the code:

HTML

```
<button onclick="toggleSidebar()"> </button>
```

JavaScript:

```
function toggleSidebar() {
 document.getElementsByClassName("sidebar").classList.toggle("active");
}
```

The button seems to be working fine when I console.log to check if it's being pressed. But, when I run the above code I keep getting that error. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName` returns a collection of elements, a collection of elements does NOT have the property `classlist`, only an element has that ... but you have nothing with the class `sidebar`

Comment: You don't have any class specified in the button element so it will fail as there is no sidebar class in your example, then you de-reference the return of getElementsByClassName which will be undefined.

Comment: @Mamun `document.getElementsByClassName("sidebar")` seems to return `undefined` - otherwise the error would tell something like `toggle is not a function`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`.getElementsByClassName()` returns a collection of matching elements. So, first you must have some elements that have the class specified.

Next, collections don't have a `classList` property. You must isolate an individual element to use `classList`, which you can do by passing an index to the returned collection:

```
button onclick="toggleSidebar()"> </button>

function toggleSidebar() {
 document.getElementsByClassName("sidebar")[0].classList.toggle("active");
}
```

With that said, [you should not be using `.getElementsByClassName()` in the first place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952088/how-to-modify-style-to-html-elements-styled-externally-with-css-using-js/54952474#54952474). Instead, use its modern counterpart, [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). Additionally, [you should not be setting up your events with inline HTML event attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991), like `onclick`. Events should be set up in JavaScript.

```js
// Get reference to the buttons and set up click event handlers
document.getElementById("side1Toggle").addEventListener("click", toggleSidebar1);
document.getElementById("side2Toggle").addEventListener("click", toggleSidebar2);

function toggleSidebar1() {
  // If there is a specific single element you want to work with use .querySelector():
  document.querySelector(".sidebar1").classList.toggle("active");
}

function toggleSidebar2() {
  // If you want to work with all the matches use .querySelectorAll():
  document.querySelectorAll(".sidebar2").forEach(function(sidebar){
    sidebar.classList.toggle("active");
  });
}
```

```css
.active { color:red; }
```

```html
<button id="side1Toggle">Click to toggle sidebar 1 Class</button>
<div class="sidebar1">This is sidebar1.</div>

<button id="side2Toggle">Click to toggle sidebar 2 Class</button>
<div class="sidebar2">This is sidebar2.</div>
<div class="sidebar2">This is sidebar2.</div>
<div class="sidebar2">This is sidebar2.</div>
<div class="sidebar2">This is sidebar2.</div>
```

Comment: @messerbill That's because in the OP's supplied code, there were no matching elements, but that's not the real issue here.